# import neo4j database from windows to ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, neo4j, backup

I have created a `neo4j` database on my windows machine.
I have transferred the content of the database directory to my linux machine. This is because I have the community edition which does not support the backup functions.

```
mtt@mttPC:/var/lib/neo4j/data/log$ sudo service neo4j-service start
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
WARNING! You are using an unsupported Java runtime. 
* Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) 7 to run Neo4j Server. Download "Java Platform (JDK) 7" from:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
* Please see http://docs.neo4j.org/ for Neo4j Server installation instructions.
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [21498]... waiting for server to be ready..... Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

The file `messages.log` in the database directory says nothing.

Any idea? Are the windows and linux `neo4j`s compatible? Thank you.

**Edit**

I have made a fresh install of neo4j on my ubuntu machine.

Now I finally get some logs:

```
2014-05-16 20:01:10.958+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Startup failed: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@25984c63' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@3d34dcb' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.: 'neostore' has a store version number that we cannot upgrade from. Expected 'NeoStore v0.A.0' but file is version 'NeoStore v0.A.2'.
2014-05-16 20:01:10.958+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Shutdown started
```

I should be related to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/PkHfgFlvfS0) but I am not sure how to proceed. Is the issue related to the fact that when I copied the database, I just stopped neo4j on my windows machine from the neo4j window?

Comment: what does data/log/*.log say? or `bin/neo4j console` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why a Neo4j database should not be transferable between operating systems. Can you please provide the output of `data/log/console.log`? First thought is that you may have permission issues. The files should be read/write for the user the Neo4j process will run as.